# Количество элементов в массиве

Tags: php

Подскажите функцию в PHP, которая считает сколько элементов в массиве. `count()` не работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хм... Ну раз count() не работает, придется написать свою функцию... )

```
function count2($a = array())
{
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($a as $t)
        $c++;
    return $c;
}
```

Как вариант...)

А вообще, count работает, если правильно использовать...)